# JSP multiple checkbox unable to capture multiple row values in a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
<input type="submit" id="Display" name="Display" value="Display" />
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" id="Update" name="Update" value="Update" /> 
<br/><br/>
<table border=1 width=90% height=30% align=center cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1>
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Name</th>
    <th>Current Value</th>
            <th>New Value</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${abc}" var="map">  
          <tr>
            <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="selectedItems" value="${map.key}" name="selectedItems" />
            </td>   
            <td align="center">${map.key}</td>
            <td align="center">${map.value}</td>
            <td align="center">
            <select name="val" id="val" >
                <option value="">Select New Value</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
            </td>
         </tr>
       </c:forEach>
</table>
```

I am constructing a dynamic table based upon the values I get in map object 'abc' on click of Display Button. Now the next step is to check one or more rows and update them by selecting a new value from dropdown. How can I capture the ${map.key} and the selected new value per row in a new map on click of 'Update'? I am able to capture the checked ${map.key} but not the corresponding selected new value from dropdown. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: idk about the update, but you can add a handler that gets value of the 2nd column? sth like `$("#val").change(function(){ console.log( this.parentNode.children[1].name); }` (I think 'this' refers to the node here)

Comment: Thanks Eric! But I am looking for something else. I am able to get values of selected dropdowns in a list but I do not know which value is for which selected key. So I need to somehow have a map for that.

Comment: I think I provide what you mean. Can you please have a closer look to what i wrote in `console.log(..)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" id="Display" name="Display" value="Display" />
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" id="Update" name="Update" value="Update" /> 
<br/><br/>
<table border=1 width=90% height=30% align=center cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1>
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Name</th>
    <th>Current Value</th>
            <th>New Value</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${abc}" var="map" varStatus="rowNumber">  
          <tr>
            <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="selectedItems" value="${map.key}=${rowNumber.index}" name="selectedItems" />
            </td>   
            <td align="center">${map.key}</td>
            <td align="center">${map.value}</td>
            <td align="center">
            <select name="val" id="val" >
                <option value="=${rowNumber.index}">Select New Value</option>
                <option value="1=${rowNumber.index}">1</option>
                <option value="2=${rowNumber.index}">2</option>
                <option value="3=${rowNumber.index}">3</option>
            </select>
            </td>
         </tr>
       </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Thank you Dileep, you idea helped. Here is how I did it. Now I can track for a particular row, what dropdown value was selected and create a map from it.

Answer (score 0):

This will do i believe..!!

```
<c:forEach items="${abc}" var="map" varStatus="rowNumber">  
          <tr>
            <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="selectedItems${rowNumber.index}" value="${map.key}" name="selectedItems[${rowNumber.index}]" />
            </td>   
            <td align="center">${map.key}</td>
            <td align="center">${map.value}</td>
            <td align="center">
            <select name="val" id="val" >
                <option value="">Select New Value</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
            </td>
         </tr>
       </c:forEach>
```

> The idea is that you must use some array for storing value for each
>   checkbox. By giving the name as `selectedItems[${rowNumber.index}]`
>   you can save the value of first `checkbox` at `selectedItems[0]`, 2nd
>   at 1 etc. All you need to do is to create an array inside the bean an
>   create getters and setters.
>
> `varStatus="rowNumber"` is used to get the current iteration index,
>   like i in the for loop. You can use this index to differentiate each
>   row.